# How can I count words frequency (one per line) in huge file (2 gb)?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program to create a 2gb (approximately) sized file of English words. And from this 2gb file trying to print the frequency of words using external sorting. After external sorting it can just print the count(frequency)

Comment: Why are you tagging java, c++, c and perl if you only wants a python answer??

Answer (score 3):

Python has a built-in function [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) which sorts an iterable. But even better than that, in versions 2.7 and greater it has a built-in collection for counting the frequencies of things. Assuming your large file has one word per line, you can do:

```
from collections import Counter
with open(<giant-dictionary>) as words:
    counts = Counter(words)
```

This will take a few minutes.

Comment: Why not use Python? (External utilities might be good if speed is _actually_ a problem.)

Comment: I'm newbie in python, but it seems a good answer, but I have a doubt, this Counter removes repeated words?

Comment: @TheCharliemops It's called "Counter" for a reason. It counts things that are fed to it, instead of storing them. When you repeat a word, that increases the count for that word.

Comment: It has sense, I didn't click it before...xD. Thanks for the answer.